# Timestamp query in mysql slow log

Tags: mysql, hibernate, connection, mysql-slow-query-log

We are receiving multiple set time stamp and autocommit statement in mysql(Inno DB) slow query log.

```
SET timestamp=1470399103;
SET autocommit=1;
```

Which are taking long time to execute,Any lead ,why these are taking long time to execute.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of these are "executing".  They are there for information about the subsequent query.

The `SET timestamp` always exists in the Slowlog (except when it is the same as the previous value).  It is there to provide the value for `NOW()` and `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` if such is in the query.  It also tells you when the query *started*.  (Note: the slowlog entries are not necessarily in timestamp-order.)

As for `SET autocommit`; I don't know.  I guess it is for similar reasons.

If you need more interpretation, please provide a longer snippet of the slowlog.